# Problems with using NGINX on an SSL-only site

Tags: nginx, ssl, proxy

I've configured a website to be 100% SSL, and its on a cPanel server with NGINX. I'm able to get the SSL part to work fine, but the IP address reported for site visitors is the IP address of the website, not the visitor's IP address.

When I get phpinfo I can see that _SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"] and _SERVER["HTTP_X_REAL_IP"] are reported correctly. Naturally, the software uses _SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] to report the visitor's IP address (I assume the server logs will use that as well).

Here is my vhost configuration:

```
server {
          error_log /var/log/nginx/vhost-error_log warn;
          listen XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:80;
          listen [::]:80;
      return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }

server {
          error_log /var/log/nginx/vhost-error_log warn;
          listen XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:443 ssl;
          listen [::]:443 ssl;
          ssl on;
          ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/bundle.crt;
          ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/ssl/bundle.key;
      server_name thenameofmysite.com;
          access_log /usr/local/apache/domlogs/thenameofmysite.com-bytes_log bytes_log;
          access_log /usr/local/apache/domlogs/thenameofmysite.com combined;
          root /home/mysite/public_html;
          #location / {
          location ~*.*\.(3gp|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|wmv|avi|asf|asx|mpg|mpeg|mp4|pls|mp3|mid|wav|swf|flv|html|htm|txt|js|css|exe|zip|tar|rar|gz|tgz|bz2|uha|7z|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|pdf|iso|woff)$ {
          expires 1M;
          try_files $uri @backend;
          }
          location / {
      error_page 405 = @backend;
          add_header X-Cache "HIT from Backend";
          proxy_pass http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8081;
          include proxy.inc;
      include microcache.inc;          
      }
          location @backend {
          internal;
          proxy_pass http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8081;
          include proxy.inc;
      include microcache.inc;
          }
          location ~ .*\.(php|jsp|cgi|pl|py)?$ {
          proxy_pass http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8081;
          include proxy.inc;
          include microcache.inc;
      }
          location ~ /\.ht {
          deny all;
          }
        }
```

The file proxy.inc contains this:

```
proxy_read_timeout   600;
proxy_buffer_size    64k;
proxy_buffers     16 32k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
proxy_pass_header Set-Cookie;
proxy_redirect     off;
proxy_hide_header  Vary;
proxy_set_header   Accept-Encoding '';
proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires;
proxy_set_header   Referer $http_referer;
proxy_set_header   Host   $host;
proxy_set_header   Cookie $http_cookie;
proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
set_real_ip_from   204.93.240.0/24;
set_real_ip_from   204.93.177.0/24;
set_real_ip_from   199.27.128.0/21;
set_real_ip_from   173.245.48.0/20;
set_real_ip_from   103.21.244.0/22;
set_real_ip_from   103.22.200.0/22;
set_real_ip_from   103.31.4.0/22;
set_real_ip_from   141.101.64.0/18;
set_real_ip_from   108.162.192.0/18;
set_real_ip_from   190.93.240.0/20;
set_real_ip_from   188.114.96.0/20;  
set_real_ip_from   197.234.240.0/22;
set_real_ip_from   198.41.128.0/17;
set_real_ip_from   162.158.0.0/15;
real_ip_header     X-Forwarded-For;
```

Any help will be appreciated!!

Comment: `nginx -V` look for `ngx_http_realip_module`. if its missing you have to rebuild nginx with `--with-http_realip_module`, check manual for your distro.

Comment: You should configure software to use right variable for client ip.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is common when any kind of proxy or CDN is used. Just change your logging statement in nginx.conf to something like this, to include $http_x_forwarded_for

```
log_format  main  '$remote_addr - "$http_x_forwarded_for" - $remote_user [$time_local] "$host" "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$request_time" '
                  '"$upstream_cache_status" "$sent_http_content_encoding" ';
```

Comment: Curious who voted me down and why - if you have feedback or a better way please let me know.

Comment: I noticed that also, I have no idea but I totally appreciate your help Tim. I just got nginx to work wiht my site as SSL-only now, but the IP address has reverted back to the site's IP address (even with this change) and I have no idea why.